# Geometry identity involving squares

Tags: geometry

Let ABCD and EFGH be two squares. If AE=a, BF=b, CG=c, and DH=d, prove that $a^2$+$c^2$=$b^2$+$d^2$.

I was able to solve it on a particular case, in which A,E,H ; B,F,E ; F,G,C and G,H,D were collinear, but I don't have any clue about the general case. Therefore, I would appreciate if you gave me an idea.
[Here is the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdbFD.png)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To supplement Blue's excellent diagram, we have, by much Pythagoras,
\begin{align}
w^2+(z+q)^2 &= a^2 \\
x^2 + (w+q)^2 &= b^2 \\
y^2 + (x+q)^2 &= c^2 \\
z^2 + (y+q)^2 &= d^2,
\end{align}
We will want to get rid of cross terms like $2zq$ and so on. We have
$$ A-p-q = z+x = w+y. $$
Then
\begin{align}
a^2+c^2 &= w^2+(z+q)^2 + y^2+(x+q)^2 \\
&= x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2 + 2(x+z)q + 2q^2 \\
&= x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2 + 2(w+y)q + 2q^2 \\
&= x^2+(w+q)^2 + z^2+(y+q)^2 \\
&= b^2+d^2.
\end{align}
It would be interesting to find out if there is an extension to, for example, similar rectangles. Or, indeed, similar quadrilaterals with corresponding vertices joined. Or other similar polygons.

Comment: +1. I didn't want to give away the whole solution but ... I guess now I don't have to. :)

Comment: @Blue I'm really glad you drew such a good diagram... was considering it myself, but it wouldn't have come out as clear as that! As usual, with the right diagram, the actual calculation is fairly simple.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea:

[image]

There's a geometric interpretation to the common value $a^2+c^2 = b^2 + d^2$ (in terms of the side-lengths of the squares, the distances between their centers, and the angle of rotation) that this doesn't capture. I haven't found an proof that features that interpretation in an "obvious" way, but I'll discuss the relation below.

---

(Note: $p$, $q$, $x$, $y$ are used differently here than above.)

First, we observe that the squares are only incidental. Let the center of the big square $\square ABCD$ be $P$, and let the center of the smaller square, call it $\square A^\prime B^\prime C^\prime D^\prime$ be $P^\prime$. We assume the vertices of the squares are named in the same orientation, so that $\overline{PA}$ moves to $\overline{PB}$ by the same kind of rotation that moves $\overline{P^\prime A^\prime}$ to $\overline{P^\prime B^\prime}$; we deduce that the angles between vectors $\overrightarrow{PX}$ and $\overrightarrow{P^\prime X^\prime}$ is a constant ---say, $2\theta$--- for $X$ and $X^\prime$ any pair of corresponding vertices. This reduces our problem to consideration of this configuration:

[image]

We have vectors $\overrightarrow{PX}$ and $\overrightarrow{P^\prime X^\prime}$ of lengths $r$ and $r^\prime$, with opposite vectors $\overrightarrow{PY}$ and $\overrightarrow{P^\prime Y^\prime}$. Defining $x := |\overline{XX^\prime}|$ and $y := |\overline{YY^\prime}|$, and choosing coordinates
$$P := \left(0,\frac12 p\right) \qquad P^\prime := \left(0,-\frac12 p\right)$$
$$X := P + r (\cos\theta, \sin\theta) \qquad X^\prime = P^\prime + r^\prime(\cos(-\theta), \sin(-\theta))$$
$$Y := P - r (\cos\theta, \sin\theta) \qquad Y^\prime = P^\prime - r^\prime(\cos(-\theta), \sin(-\theta))$$

we compute
$$\begin{align}
x^2 + y^2 &= |X-X^\prime|^2 + |Y-Y^\prime|^2 \\
&= |((r-r^\prime)\cos\theta,p + ( r + r^\prime) \sin\theta)|^2 + |-(r-r^\prime)\cos\theta, p- (r+r^\prime)\sin\theta)|^2 \\
&= (r-r^\prime)^2\cos^2\theta + p^2 + ( r + r^\prime)^2\sin^2\theta + 2 p ( r + r^\prime) \sin\theta \\
&+ (r-r^\prime)^2\cos^2\theta + p^2 + (r-r^\prime)^2\sin^2\theta - 2 p ( r + r^\prime) \sin\theta \\
&= 2 p^2 + 2 r^2 + 2 (r^\prime)^2 - 4 r r^\prime( \cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta) \\
&= 2 \left( p^2 + r^2 + (r^\prime)^2 - 2 r r^\prime \cos 2\theta \right) \tag{$\star$}
\end{align}$$

Introducing $X^{\prime\prime}$ such that $\square PP^\prime X^\prime X^{\prime\prime}$ is a parallelogram, we have $\angle X P X^{\prime\prime} = 2\theta$.

[image]

Therefore, defining $q := |\overline{XX^{\prime\prime}}|$, we can invoke the Law of Cosines to write $(\star)$ simply as
$$x^2 + y^2 = 2( p^2 + q^2 ) \tag{$\star\star$}$$

The above is independent of the choice of $X$ among the vertices of $\square ABCD$. (Of course, that choice determines $X^\prime$, $Y$, and $Y^\prime$.) Therefore, $x^2+y^2$ is a constant for all such choices. In the original square problem, this says exactly that $a^2 + c^2 = b^2 + d^2 = 2 ( p^2 + q^2 )$.

As @Chappers anticipated, however, the result isn't restricted to squares. Relation $(\star\star)$ holds for $X$, $Y$, $X^\prime$, $Y^\prime$ taken among the vertices of *any pair of similar, centrally-symmetric, cyclic polygons*: similarity (in matching orientations) ensures the constancy of the angle $2\theta$ between $\overrightarrow{PX}$ and $\overrightarrow{PX^\prime}$; central symmetry guarantees a diametrically-opposite $Y$ for every $X$; cyclicity gives us the constant $r$ (and $r^\prime$, hence also $q$).

Further generalization is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some help, (assuming everything is vectors):

$$\begin{cases}EH=FG\\ FE=GH\\ a+EH+D = AD\\ a+EF+b= AB\\ b+FG+c=BC\\ c+GH+d = CD\\ CD = -AB\\ AD=BC\end{cases}$$

For the big two letters $XY$ and $YX$ of course this must hold: $$XY = -YX$$